# VectorDensityPlot options for vector style not working if vector field includes replacement rules

Tags: plotting, graphics, bugs, replacement

I am trying to modify the thickness, color, style, etc. of vectors in a VectorDensityPlot.

After some testing, I realised my problem was caused by having:

- Replacement rules in the vector field expression
- A **function** e.g. F[A_,y_,z_] = {A z, -A y} of parameters that I specified in the plotting command, e.g. F[2,y0,z0].

I copy here a minimal code that reproduces this issue. What is the reason for this behaviour?

```
VectorDensityPlot[
 ({A z0, -A y0} /. {A -> 2}),
 {y0, -1, 1},
 {z0, -1, 1},
 VectorStyle -> {"Drop", Red}
 ]
```

ignores the VectorStyle options and uses the defaults, while

```
VectorDensityPlot[
 ({2 z0, -2 y0} ),
 {y0, -1, 1},
 {z0, -1, 1},
 VectorStyle -> {"Drop", Red}
 ]
```

works.

[image: VectorDensityPlot results]

**EDIT: As noted by a comment from user Henrik Schumacher, adding Evaluate[] to the vector field fixes the problem. I would very much like to understand what is the reason for this.**

Comment: What version of Mathematica are you using? I have had issues with plotting specifications on older versions (sub ~11.2).

Comment: I don't know for sure why this happens, but using `Evaluate` seems to make it working: `VectorDensityPlot[
 Evaluate[({A z0, -A y0} /. {A -> 2})],
 {y0, -1, 1}, {z0, -1, 1},
 VectorStyle -> {"Drop", Red}
 ]`

Comment: This happens in both Mathematica 10 and 11.3.

Comment: Thanks @Henrik Schumacher. Adding Evaluate does fix it. My question now would be: Why?

Comment: I don't know why this works in this particular case. But it is often a good idea to fully evaluate an expression before it is sent to plotting commands.

Comment: I've reported it internally.

Answer (score 1):

The first argument has a [`Head`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Head.html) of [`ReplaceAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html), where as the second is [`List`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/List.html)

```
({A z0, -A y0} /. {A -> 2})
```

is full form is

```
ReplaceAll[List[Times[A, z0], Times[Times[-1, A], y0]], List[Rule[A, 2]]]
```

At the time to assign Styles, *Mathematica* checks is the various elements to plot match the structure of the Style elements, so they can be assigned one-to-one.

I think the problem is similar to this example:

Here there is a list of three expressions to plot, matching the list of three [`PlotStyle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotStyle.html) directives.

```
Plot[
 {x, 2 x, 3 x}
 , {x, 0, 1}
 , PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue}
 ]
```

[image]

on the contrary, this other example there is an expression with a `Head` of  `Times` that does NOT match the `PlotStyle` option structure.

```
Plot[
 x Range[3]
 , {x, 0, 1}
 , PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Using `Evaluate` forces the expression to be evaluated into a structure that matches both the argument and the Style.